# msvs pro 2012 installshield limited edition, merge module "file not on local computer"

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-xp, installshield

I switched MSVS 2012 (C++) to the Platform toolset that also supports XP. Now Installshield LE wont create an installer anymore, bacause the corresponding merge modules are missing. In the Installshield-Configuration > 2-Specify Application Data > Redistributables, four items are checked: "Visual C++ 8.0 MFC (x86) WinSXS MSM, (two more for MFC and one for OpenMP). However, in the location column it says: "File not on local computer".
Maybe a stupid question: How do I get these files? (they actually seem not to be on my machine, I searched for *.msm).

thanks!!

Comment: That's a merge module for VS2005, seven years and 3 major versions ago.  Is this intentional?  High odds that you want to move the clock forward and use the VS2012 version, version number 11.0 (not 8.0)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Actually I'm not keen on using these. As mentioned above, I switched to the PlatformToolset V110 XP in order to be able and build for XP again. I suspected that these files were thus automatically selected. Looks like I may be mistaken. I unchecked these and checked the latest (110) ones. Thing is, since upgrading to MSVS 2012 I dont'get my project to run any more. I can build the exe, works fine. When I use the Installshield Package to install the app on another computer, I always get "xxx is not a valid win32 app". That's actually the issue I'm trying to fix.